# how to call a function after press "on action selected" in react native Toolbar

Tags: toolbar, react-native

I implemented a React native Toolbar its showing me all actions which i have given but after press on that any action it gives me error. Its entering in the function that `onActionSelected` But after that my `Logout()` , `Move()` any function is not working.

where i am going wrong plz help

code:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
        title="Shopcon"
        style={styles.toolbar}
        actions={toolbarActions}
        onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}
         />

const toolbarActions = [
 {title: 'Logout', show: 'never'},
 {title: 'Got to Login', show: 'never'},
 ];


onActionSelected(position) {

if (position === 0) { 
  console.log("I am in 0");
  this.Logout();
}
if (position === 1) { 
  console.log("I am in 1");
  this.Move();
}
}


async Logout() {
 console.log("fun1");
 const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
 try {
   await AsyncStorage.removeItem(STORAGE_KEY);
   Alert.alert("Logout Success! Token:" + DEMO_TOKEN)
 } catch (error) {
   console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
 }
  navigate("Login");
}

Move(){
  console.log("fun2")
  const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
  navigate("Login");
}
```

both are entering in `onActionSelected(position)` function but not entering in those other functions.

where i am going wrong please help.

Comment: Are you using `bind` on `this.onActionSelected`?

Comment: No i am not using that keyword overall in my code

Comment: change `onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected}` to `onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected.bind(this)}`

Comment: Yes Its Working now... thank you so much.

Comment: can you write it in answer so i can do green mark to it and others like me cant be stuck for such problem.

Comment: Good. Next time when you are asking a question please try to give better indentation to your code and please if you are getting any errors add the complete error message. It will help you to get better and faster answer.

Comment: @bennygenel k will correct my mistakes, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158993/discussion-between-mayuresh-patil-and-bennygenel).